# How to change visibility of button in activity from activity recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to change the visibility of "Proceed to card" button,
to visible when the user clicks on add button and back to invisible when all the items got removed :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jecpw.png)

> VISIBILITY is set to INVISIBLE in layout

I have added a count variable to compare

**RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter.kt**

```
package com.himanshu.hungerhunt.adapter

import com.himanshu.hungerhunt.R
import com.himanshu.hungerhunt.model.FoodMenu
import com.himanshu.hungerhunt.databse.FoodEntity
import com.himanshu.hungerhunt.activity.RestaurantMenuActivity
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.view.View
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, private val itemList: ArrayList<FoodMenu>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter.RestaurantMenuViewHolder>() {
    var total: Int = 0
    var count = 0

    class RestaurantMenuViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val txtFoodId: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodId)
        val txtFoodName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodName)
        val txtFoodPrice: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodPrice)
        val btnAddFood: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RestaurantMenuViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_food_item, parent, false)
        return RestaurantMenuViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RestaurantMenuViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val foodMenu = itemList[position]

        val foodName = foodMenu.foodName
        val foodId = foodMenu.foodId
        val foodPrice = foodMenu.foodPrice

        holder.txtFoodId.text = (position + 1).toString()
        holder.txtFoodName.text = foodMenu.foodName
        holder.txtFoodPrice.text = foodMenu.foodPrice

        val foodEntity = FoodEntity(foodId, foodName, foodPrice)

        holder.btnAddFood.setOnClickListener {
            val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
                context.getSharedPreferences("Cart Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            if (!RestaurantMenuActivity.DBAsyncTask(context, foodEntity, 1).execute().get()) {
                val async = RestaurantMenuActivity.DBAsyncTask(context, foodEntity, 2).execute()
                val result = async.get()
                if (result) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "${holder.txtFoodName.text} Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    holder.btnAddFood.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightOrange)
                    holder.btnAddFood.text = "Remove"
                    total += foodMenu.foodPrice.toInt()
                    count += 1
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("total", total).apply()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                val async = RestaurantMenuActivity.DBAsyncTask(context, foodEntity, 3).execute()
                val result = async.get()
                if (result) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "${holder.txtFoodName.text} Removed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    holder.btnAddFood.setBackgroundResource(R.color.materialRed)
                    holder.btnAddFood.text = "Add"
                    total -= foodMenu.foodPrice.toInt()
                    count -= 1
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("total", total).apply()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I have tried this

```
RestaurantMenuActivity().btnProceedToCart.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnProceedToCart).visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

> But it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use interface that will notify you in your activity when click on addFood button in your adapter.

First, make the interface in your adapter.

```
class RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, private val itemList: 
ArrayList<FoodMenu>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter.RestaurantMenuViewHolder>() {

   interface RestaurantMenuListener {
     fun onAddClick()
   }

}
```

Secondly, pass the interface in your adapter from the activity along with the other parameters that you are passing.

```
class RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, private val itemList: 
ArrayList<FoodMenu>,val mCallBack : RestaurantMenuistener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter.RestaurantMenuViewHolder>() {

   interface RestaurantMenuistener {
     fun onAddClick()
   }

}
```

And in your activity,

```
adapter = RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter(context,itemlist, Object: 
RestaurantMenuRecyclerAdapter.RestaurantMenuistener{
  override fun onAddClick(){
     //Do your stuff here like hide or show.
  }
})
```

Finally, in your adapter when you click on add button,

```
holder.btnAddFood.setOnClickListener {
  mCallback.onAddClick()
}
```